# Expression size exceeds max in Google AMP State

Tags: reactjs, jsx, amp-html

I've to calculate a cost range on the tap of different labels.
I'm updating Google AMP state on each radio button tap according to the use case.

```
// data from mockapi
const costData = [
    {
        "label": "Treatment 1",
        "cost": "20,000 - 30,000"
    },
    {
        "label": "Treatment 2",
        "cost": "10,000 - 20,000"
    },
    {
        "label": "Treatment 3",
        "cost": "10,000 - 20,000"
    },
    .....
    .....
    .....
]


// component
const TreatmentLabels = (props) => {
    const costArr = cost.cost.split("-");
    const lowCost = parseInt(costArr[0].replace(",", "").trim());
    const highCost = parseInt(costArr[1].replace(",", "").trim());

    return costData.map((costObj) => {
        <span on={`tap:AMP.setState(
                { totalEstimatedCostRange: {
                  low: totalEstimatedCostRange.low == undefined
                        ? (selectedChoice.subtype == 'type_1'
                            ? 79000
                            : selectedChoice.subtype == 'type_2'
                              ? 96000
                              : 126000
                            ) + totalEstimatedCostRange.low + ${lowCost}
                        : labelWithSelect == '${cost.label}'
                          ? totalEstimatedCostRange.low - ${lowCost}
                          : totalEstimatedCostRange.low + ${lowCost},
                  high: totalEstimatedCostRange.high == undefined
                        ? (selectedChoice.subtype == 'type_1'
                            ? 115000
                            : selectedChoice.subtype == 'type_2'
                              ? 140000
                              : 190000
                            ) + totalEstimatedCostRange.high + ${highCost}
                        : labelWithSelect == '${cost.label}'
                          ? totalEstimatedCostRange.high - ${highCost}
                          : totalEstimatedCostRange.high + ${highCost},
                },
                labelWithSelect: labelWithSelect['${cost.label}'] == undefined ? true : !labelWithSelect['${cost.label}']
              })
              }`>
            {costObj.label}
        </span>

        <p>
            ₹{" "}
            <span data-amp-bind-text="totalEstimatedCostRange.low == undefined
                                      ? selectedChoice.subtype == 'type_1'
                                          ? 79000 
                                          : selectedChoice.subtype == 'type_2'
                                              ? 96000
                                              : 126000
                                      : totalEstimatedCostRange.low"></span>
            -{" "}
             <span data-amp-bind-text="totalEstimatedCostRange.high == undefined
                                       ? selectedChoice.subtype == 'type_1'
                                           ? 115000
                                           : selectedChoice.subtype == 'type_2'
                                               ? 140000
                                               : 190000
                                       : totalEstimatedCostRange.high"></span>
        </p>
    });
}
```

But on the label tap, Console shows the expression size exceeded error

[image]

Am i doing anything wrong here, or how can i solve this error.
Any help would be appreciated since, I'm trying to solve this since last 2 days.

Thanks in advance

Comment: there are several limits on `amp-script`: target DOM objects, script-size and script-runtime. Looks like you've exceeded the script-size. What happens if you minimize?

Comment: @JayGray, Minimizing doesn't bring any effect here

Comment: can you make it work if you strip functionality (for testing purposes only)? Or, reduce the number of items to reduce the size? another idea is to use `fetch` to source the data, rather than the inline structure. `fetch` endpoint will have to be HTTPS and CORS. there is a `fetch` example in AMP documentation. I don't see any other issues with the code, except for the size issue flagged in the error message.